# 402:Unknown Client error when subscribing to a <<moduleName>>/<<statementName>>

Tags: cumulocity

I have been working with the Cumulocity API through Postman.

I can perform a handshake and get a successful response.
I can subscribe to a channel using `<<moduleName>>/*`

But if I include a specific statement name, it returns

> 402:Unknown client error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to say"moduleName/*"

Comment: Is it possible to post the sample request here? Normally, you get this error if you do not replace the "{{clientId}}" with the client ID returned from the handshake.

Comment: Definitely put in the client id, which was returned by the handshake.

Comment: Proof that the clientid is there is that this works with /newmodule/* but not if i put the statement name in.

Answer (score 0):

Andre,

I redid the handshake, then updated the clientId and then tried again and got a 403, which you answered here:

[Subcribe a channel / real-time notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148052/subcribe-a-channel-real-time-notification)